# вопрос про анимацию при скролле

Tags: javascript, анимация, прокрутка

делаю анимацию с помощью Gsap и ScrollTrigger, но дело в том, что иногда(при слишком быстром скролле или
когда решат иллюминаты) анимация не срабатывает вообще. А в гугле ничего не нахожу по этому поводу,
как будто только у меня такая проблема и руки из жопы.

```
    const timeLine = gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger:{
        trigger:'.team__inner',
        start:'top center'
    },
});

timeLine.from('.card1',{x:-(cardWidth*1.5), duration:0.9})
        .from('.card2',{x:-(cardWidth*2.5), duration:0.9})
        .from('.card3',{x:-(cardWidth*3.5), duration:0.9})
```